# How to setup internet explorer favourites for members of a domain?

Tags: windows, domain, internet-explorer

Is it possible to setup [internet explorer favourites](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ID/internet-explorer/add-view-organize-favorites) for everyone (or perhaps a group) on a domain?

We have a number of favourites that would be useful to share with all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through Group Policy pretty simply. When setting up a new GPO, under the User section you can find the place to add URLs, Favorites and things at Policies -> Windows Settings -> Internet Explorer -> URLs. There you will find two areas to set things, Favorites and URLs. Favorites is what you're looking for. URLs is for things like default home-page and custom search engine settings.

When set this way everyone will get them to which the GPO applies. You can do quite a lot with IE and GPOs, search for "Internet Explorer Admin Kit," or IEAK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of accomplishing this that works with Internet Explorer 10+

> User configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Shortcuts: New Shortcut
>
> Action: Replace
>
> Name: %USERPROFILE%\Favorites\Links\Name of Favourite
>
> Target Type: URL
>
> Location: <Specify full path>
>
> Target URL: http://www.urloffavourite.com/
>
> Common tab: CHECKED - Remove this item when it is no longer applied

I found out recently that [Internet Explorer Maintenance (IEM) settings have been deprecated in favour of Group Policy Preferences, Administrative Templates (.admx), and the Internet Explorer Administration Kit (IEAK)](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn338129.aspx).  So this is the only way I've found so far that works for IE7+ including IE10 and IE11.